# I am trying to replicate an ecommerce system using a DApp and want to know how to decrement product quantity

Tags: solidity

For my class project I am trying to replicate ebay on a DApp. When a buyer buys something from a seller, the wallet shows ether transacted, I also want to show quantity transacted. E.g.

Jan 1 2018:

Seller A has 0 ether and 10 carrots costing 2 ethers each
Buyer B has 10 ether and 0 carrots costing 0 ethers each

Jan 2 2018:

Buyer buys 2 carrots costing 1 ether each, costing .2 ether for transaction
Seller A has 2 ether and 8 carrots costing 2 ethers each
Buyer B has 7.8 ether and 2 carrots costing 2 ethers each

How do I include the quantity of carrots in solidity and show increment for buyer and decrement for seller?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the carrots in a mapping keyed by the accounts.

mapping (address => uint) carrots;

carrots[0x0SELLER....] would hold the number of carrots the seller has.

When someone calls the buyCarrots() function you would do something like this:

```
function buyCarrotsFromSeller(address _seller) payable {
  uint carrotsToBuy = carrotPrice / msg.value; // You would need to extend this to account for change and rounding errors.

  require(carrots[_seller] >= carrotsToBuy);

  carrots[_seller] -= carrotsToBuy;
  carrots[msg.sender] += carrotsToBuy;

  // Finally, transfer the ether paid for the carrots to the seller
  _seller.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, will try this out right away and let you know if this works..